# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl support for iOS 3.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog, transition

According to the iPhone doc this particular modal transition is available for iOS version 3.2 and up. Yet i know my phone (running 3.1.3 i think) can do this curling transition because of the Google Maps app.

Is there another way/trick to get this curling transition for iOS versions < 3.2 ?

Thanks!

Comment: Just because one of Apple's built-in applications does something does not mean that we have public access to do the same.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But we are currently at iOS 4.0, AND the docs says that the modal curling transition is supported in iOS 3.2 and up.

Comment: So im just wondering why the doc says is suppoted in iOS 3.2 and up when a previous version can clearly do it (e.g. google maps). This makes me wonder if there is a trick or an exposed API (im hoping the doc that i was reading is outdated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` was a private API before 3.2. In 3.2 it was documented and made public.

I would think that if you link against SDK 4.1, but target 3.1.3 devices, the app won't be rejected by Apple.

Comment: I haven't submitted it yet, so i dont know if there's any reason to assume it would be rejected. All I know is that under the simulator the transition effect works, but on the device it doesnt.

Comment: THe device is a 3G running iOS 3.1.3 i believe. Hmm, i guess this answers my question - I should upgrade to iOS 3.2!

Comment: you might have a little trouble upgrading an iPhone to 3.2.